# ExtJS: controller function placement

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4 and abiding by their MVC pattern. I'm a little confused on where to put helper functions used by event handlers. This is currently what I'm doing:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.myController, {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller.
   stores: [...],
   models: [...],
   views: [...],

   init: function() {
       this.control({
           'selector' : {
               event1: this.onEvent1,
               event2: this.onEvent2
           }
       });
   },

   onEvent1: function(args) {
       // do stuff
       helperFn();
   },
   onEvent2: function(args) {
       // do other stuff
       helperFn();
   }
});

// is this 'right'?
function helperFn() {                           
    // do other, other stuff
}
```

Is this the correct setup? Or should I do something like:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.myController, {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller.
   stores: [...],
   models: [...],
   views: [...],

   init: function() {
       this.control({
           'selector' : {
               event1: this.onEvent1.bind(this),
               event2: this.onEvent2.bind(this)
           }
       });
   },

   onEvent1: function(args) {
       // do stuff
       this.helperFn();
   },
   onEvent2: function(args) {
       // do other stuff
       this.helperFn();
   },
   helperFn(): function() {
       // do other, other stuff
   }
});
```

Is one style preferred? I.e. are there any major drawbacks of either one compared to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By defining your helper function outside of the controller's definition, you're making it a global function.  This means that the function will be available everywhere in your application.  If this is a requirement, I would define a separate utility singleton which contains `helperFn`.

```
//in a separate file...
Ext.define('App.Util', {
    singleton: true,

    helperFn: function() {
        // do other, other stuff
    }
});

Ext.define('App.controller.myController, {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller.
   stores: [...],
   models: [...],
   views: [...],

   init: function() {
       this.control({
           'selector' : {
               event1: this.onEvent1.bind(this),
               event2: this.onEvent2.bind(this)
           }
       });
   },

   onEvent1: function(args) {
       // do stuff
       App.Util.helperFn();
   },
   onEvent2: function(args) {
       // do other stuff
       App.Util.helperFn();
   }
});
```

By defining it inside the controller's definition, you're making it a member of the controller class.  This means that it can be called by the instance of the controller only.  This is generally preferred if the code is specific to the controller.

There is a third option available.  If you want the function to be available only within the controller, but not accessible to anything else (similar to a private method in Java), you can set it up like this:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.myController', (function () {

   //now the function is only available below through closure
   function helperFn() {
      // do other, other stuff
   }

   return {
      extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
      stores: [...],
      models: [...],
      views: [...],

      init: function () {
         this.control({
            '
            selector ': {
               event1: this.onEvent1.bind(this),
               event2: this.onEvent2.bind(this)
            }
         });
      },

      onEvent1: function (args) {
         // do stuff
         helperFn();
      },
      onEvent2: function (args) {
         // do other stuff
         helperFn();
      }
   };
})());
```

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, a traditional OOP-like styling is what I was going for - thanks for pointing out the global thing, and thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: Defining a Utility class with helper functions is what I do, I feel it to be a very elegant and DRY solution. +1

Comment: I would be careful with singletons; my rule of thumb is any code that needs to be aware of its scope belongs to a class with that scope. Utility singletons are good for really simplistic functions that have no side effects, but I'd suggest not using them just to share the code between two classes. Inheritance and mixins work just fine for that. Passing the scope around like above is a big red flag in my book - six months from now you'll find yourself scratching your head trying to grok what comes from where, and you'll have to debug it instead of just reading the code.

Comment: @AlexTokarev I agree completely, but without knowing what `helperFn` does, it's hard to say where it belongs.